# Create workbooks from a template workbook within a loop

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to filter data from a large table, filter it, and copy the filtered data to a new worksheet. Below is the code I have - which works, but takes over a minute to complete.

My ultimate goal is to take a template workbook (that includes all my data) and create sub-workbooks based on the filtered data. I tried creating sub-workbooks using `SaveCopyAs` but I ended up losing my original data. So, I was trying to copy the filtered data to a different worksheet as a workaround.

```
    wsDV.ListObjects("DVTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=wsMaster.Range("F" & x)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    wsDV.ListObjects("DVTable").HeaderRowRange.Copy Destination:=wsSalary.Range("C3")
    wsDV.ListObjects("DVTable").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    wsSalary.Range("C4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: try to convert table in "template workbook" to range then do the rest....I hope it will execute fast..

Comment: Where is the loop you're talking about? Are you trying to do something in a loop - or already doing it in a loop you're not showing us? You have code that works - but just for one workbook - is that correct?

Comment: the loop is not shown, but basically is used to determine the range filter and saves the workbook as that file name. The code above works to copy...it's just too slow. the loop code doesn't work, because my original workbook gets overridden after the filter is applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's small Application changes you can do to tweak the speed.

**Turn off updates and events** (make sure to turn them back on afterwards!)

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

But biggest improvements will come from removing copy/paste operations - especially using clipboard - and you can do this if you're just pasting values.

**Adding Range values directly**

Change this:

```
wsDV.ListObjects("DVTable").HeaderRowRange.Copy Destination:=wsSalary.Range("C3")
wsDV.ListObjects("DVTable").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
wsSalary.Range("C4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

To this:

```
Dim rgeFrom     As Range
Dim rgeTo       As Range

Dim numCols     As Long
Dim startCol    As Long
Dim startRow    As Long

Dim endCol      As Long
Dim endRow      As Long

Set rgeFrom = wsDV.ListObjects("DVTable").HeaderRowRange
numCols = rgeFrom.Columns.Count
numRows = rgeFrom.Rows.Count

startCol = 3 ' wsSalary Start Cell C3 
startRow = 3

endCol = startCol + numCols - 1
endRow = startRow + numRows - 1

Set rgeTo = Range(Cells(startRow, startCol), Cells(endRow, endCol))

rgeTo.Value = rgeFrom.Value

' Do same for next range DataBodyRange

Set rgeFrom = wsDV.ListObjects("DVTable").DataBodyRange
numCols = rgeFrom.Columns.Count
numRows = rgeFrom.Rows.Count

startCol = 3 ' wsSalary Start Cell C4
startRow = 4

endCol = startCol + numCols - 1
endRow = startRow + numRows - 1

Set rgeTo = Range(Cells(startRow, startCol), Cells(endRow, endCol))

rgeTo.Value = rgeFrom.Value
```